# Unable to upgrade MID Server

Tags: configuration-management, discovery, servicenow, cmdb

Our ServiceNOW instance recently got upgraded from Eureka to Geneva.
MID Server status became down and the version does not match the Build number in the stats.
I was told that the MID Server will auto upgrade which didn't happened. I am using a proxy server to connect, when I tried communicating with the instance through the server it is working however I assume the service or application installed is not able to communicate with the instance.
I created a new service and it worked perfectly for 1 min however after that the status of it became down.
Then I tried changing the configurations of old services however no good.
Now the services are running fine however in the config file in the mid_sys_id section mid server details not getting populated and the status of the MID Server in the instance is always down.
Do I need to change any properties in the instance?
Since I use proxy server do I need to remove the comment line of the auto upgrade through proxy section or can I leave that blank?

What is the issue here? Why my MID Server is not getting upgraded? Kindly help me.. If possible an explanation with screen shot would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Geneva, you should be able to simply go to your MIDServer listing, from inside your instance, click on a MIDServer, and find 'Upgrade MID' in the Related links section.  That should start an upgrade for that MID Server.  If it fails, there should be an entry in either the ServiceNow logs or the MID Server logs with more information why it failed.

[image: A Related Links list, where Upgrade MID is the last item]